# Action script 3, Registration, Data sent to php, but AS3 won't display data back but have no Error

Tags: php, actionscript-3, actionscript, registration, user-registration

I am new to Php and AS3, i am trying to set up a registration page, the AS3 will send the data to php and then it should return a message saying you are successfully registered.
The AS3 at the moment does send all the data to the database. But the AS3 does not display the message that it has been successfully registered, but it also display no error. Please help

My AS3 code

```
stop();



// build variable name for the URL Variables loader
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables;

// Build the varSend variable
var varSend:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/dummy.php");
varSend.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
varSend.data = variables;

// Build the varLoader variable
var varLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
varLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
varLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);


// handler for the PHP script completion and return of status

  function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
  if(event.target.data && event.target.data.return_msg)
   status_txt.text = event.target.data.return_msg

} 


// Add event listener for submit button click
submit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ValidateAndSend);

// function ValidateAndSend
function ValidateAndSend (event:MouseEvent):void {

// validate fields
if(!name_txt.length) {
status_txt.text = "Please enter your name";
} else if (!email_txt.length) {
status_txt.text = "Please enter your email";
} else if (!pass_txt.length) {
status_txt.text = "Please enter your password";
} else { 


// ready the variables in our form for sending
variables.username = name_txt.text;
variables.email = email_txt.text; 
variables.password = pass_txt.text;

        // if error occurs


// Send the data to PHP now
varLoader.load(varSend);


} // close else condition for error handling

}
```

Below is my php code

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);
include 'connect.php';


{
 //get form data
 $username = ($_POST['username']);
 $password = ($_POST['password']);
 $email = ($_POST['email']);

 if (!$username||!$password||!$email)
 {
     $fill= "Please fill out all fields";
 echo ($fill) ;
 }

 else
 {
    //encrypt password
    $password = md5($password);

    //check if username already taken
    $check = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Test WHERE username = '$username'") or die( mysqli_error());
    if (mysqli_num_rows($check)>=1)
    {
    echo "return_msg=Username_already_taken";}

    else
    {




           //register into database
            mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Test (username,password,email) VALUES 
                ('$username','$password','$email');") or die(mysqli_error());
        }


    echo "return_msg=success" ;    


 }

 }


?>
```

Thanks so much for your time and help

Comment: start by tracing your response...  in `completeHandler` before your conditional logic put `trace('this happened: ' + event.target.data);`  and see what you are getting back.

Comment: I put that after the completehandler and i got this in the output, i don't really know what i should be looking at. 
Fonts should be embedded for any text that may be edited at runtime, other than text with the "Use Device Fonts" setting. Use the Text > Font Embedding command to embed fonts.
[SWF] t.swf - 531607 bytes after decompression
this happened: %0A%0A%20%20return%5Fmsg=success%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A

Comment: I am not sure why that is there either, but that is what php is returning to your AS.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your response when tracing the `event.target.data`, php is sending a response.  you are not seeing anything because of the conditional logic.  event.target.data does exist but not `event.target.data.return_msg`.

you can remove the conditional logic and have

```
function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
    status_txt.text = event.target.data
}
```

this will provide you with the string returned from your php.  you can use trim to clear the whitespace (the url_encoded characters in your test response), then split it on the `=` sign if you like.  I personally like to use `JSON` notation to communicate with AS3 and PHP...

EDIT ADDED :

There is a StringHelper class mentioned in the [Adobe Docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html) but I use the following function in my DocumentClass to trim responses:

```
public static function trim(s:String):String{
    return s.replace(/^([\s|\t|\n]+)?(.*)([\s|\t|\n]+)?$/gm, "$2");
}
```

Comment: I used unescape() to clear the url_encoded characters, because i am not sure how to trim out the clear space. But i am left with lots of space. Wondering if you would know, what should i do? Or how do i trim out the spaces?

Comment: I editted my answer to include the `trim` function I use for that purpose.